# How to kill a process in C?

Tags: c, kill

I'm currently trying to display a picture each time the user makes an input.

But I wanna close the previous picture and I struggle doing it in C.

What I'm doing looks like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    system("display /tmp/pic.png & echo $! > /tmp/pid.txt");
    FILE* file = fopen ("/tmp/pid.txt", "r");
    char strpid[10];
    fscanf (file, "%s", strpid);
    fclose(file);
    printf("%s\n",strpid);
    system(strcat("kill ",strpid));
}
```

So I display my picture, I keep the it's pid in a text file then when I don't need it anymore, I read this file and try to kill it.

I also tried using kill from <signal.h>

```
fscanf (file, "%d", intpid);    
kill(intpid)
```

and it did not work too.

I'm probably doing something wrong but I can't see what, does someone know?

Thanks :).

Comment: `strcat("kill ",strpid)` You can't add to a string literal.

Comment: Besides that, you create the task then immediately attempt to kill it. You need to reverse the operations: if there is a pid file, read it and kill the previous task. Then, start the new display task.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I know that, it's just that I'm always asked to give a reproducible example so I just inverted it so that it'd output the error directly.

And thank you for the string literal thing, I didn't know it existed lol.

Comment: Obligatory comment:  `system()` is generally bad practice.  Just read the linux man page "caveat's" section for a general idea why.